# Using Bootstrap collapse class not working for multiple div tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list of item A, B, C, D, E. Each item you click on one of these list items there is a bootstrap class 'collapse' which shows a div with text in it. This all works ok. However, you have to click the list item again to collapse the div with the text in it.

I am trying to make sure when a list item is clicked on, all other openend divs are closed immediately.

I found something which mentions to use 'data-parent' but as seen in the snippet below this does not work. To see the problem view the snippet and expand snippet.

To replicate my problem these are the steps:

1. Click item A (you will see text appear 'A' underneath)
2. Click item B (you will see text 'A' still appear as well as 'B')
3. Click item C (you will see text 'A','B''C')
4. Click item A (you will now see 'B','C') but A has now collapsed

I am trying to make sure you only see the text related to the ID of the div you clicked on.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <!-- Start Restaurant Menu -->
         <section id="mu-restaurant-menu">
             <div class="container">
                 <div id="menuGroup">
                     <div class="panel">
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                     <div class="mu-restaurant-menu-area">
                        <div class="mu-title">
                           <p>&nbsp;</p>
                           <h2>LIST ITEM</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-md-12">
                              
                              <div class="mu-counter-area">
                                 <ul class="mu-counter-nav">
                                    <li class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                       <div class="mu-single-counter" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseA" aria-expanded="false" data-parent="#menuGroup" aria-controls="collapseFood">
                                          <span>A</span>
                                       </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                       <div class="mu-single-counter" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseB" aria-expanded="false" data-parent="#menuGroup" aria-controls="collapseVegan">
                                          <span>B</span>
                                       </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                       <div class="mu-single-counter" data-toggle="collapse"   href="#collapseC" aria-expanded="false" data-parent="#menuGroup" aria-controls="collapseJain">
                                          <span>C</span>
                                       </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                       <div class="mu-single-counter" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseD" aria-expanded="false" data-parent="#menuGroup" aria-controls="collapseLunch">
                                          <span>D</span>
                                       </div>
                                    </li>
                                 
                                    <li class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                       <div class="mu-single-counter" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseE" aria-expanded="false" data-parent="#menuGroup" aria-controls="collapseCocktail">
                                          <span>E</span>
                                       </div>
                                    </li>
                                 </ul>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mu-restaurant-menu-content">
                           <div class="row visible-lg visible-md visible-sm visible-xs collapsable-content">
                              <div class="container">
                                 <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                    <div class="main-menu-box">
                                       <hr>
            
            
            
            
                                       <div class="collapse" id="collapseA" aria-expanded="true" >
                                          <div class="intro">
            A
                                             </div>
                                          <hr>
                                       </div>

             <div class="collapse" id="collapseB" aria-expanded="true" >
                                          <div class="intro">
            B
                                             </div>
                                          <hr>
                                       </div>
                                      
                                            <div class="collapse" id="collapseC" aria-expanded="true" >
                                          <div class="intro">
            C
                                             </div>
                                          <hr>
                                       </div>
                                      
                                         <div class="collapse" id="collapseD" aria-expanded="true" >
                                          <div class="intro">
            D
                                             </div>
                                          <hr>
                                       </div>

                                      
                                           
                                         <div class="collapse" id="collapseE" aria-expanded="true" >
                                          <div class="intro">
            E
                                             </div>
                                          <hr>
                                       </div>
  





                                                      </div>
                                                   </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <hr>
                                             </div>
                                          </div>






                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
                   </div>
                 </div>
                 </div>
                </div>
         </section>
         <!-- End Restaurant Menu -->
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with jquery like,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="collapse"]').click(function(event) {
        if ($('.collapse.in').length > 0) {
            $('.collapse.in').collapse('hide')
        }
    });
  })
</script>
```

On `data-toggle="collapse"` click, means on your list items click, all the div's which are opened (have the .in class with them) are close with the [collapse function](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_collapse.asp).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
            <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
                </script>
                <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js">
                </script>
            </link>
        </meta>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Start Restaurant Menu -->
        <section id="mu-restaurant-menu">
            <div class="container">
                <div id="menuGroup">
                    <div class="panel">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="mu-restaurant-menu-area">
                                    <div class="mu-title">
                                        <p>
                                        </p>
                                        <h2>
                                            LIST ITEM
                                        </h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <div class="mu-counter-area">
                                                <ul class="mu-counter-nav">
                                                    <li class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                                        <div aria-controls="collapseFood" aria-expanded="false" class="mu-single-counter" data-parent="#menuGroup" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseA">
                                                            <span>
                                                                A
                                                            </span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                                        <div aria-controls="collapseVegan" aria-expanded="false" class="mu-single-counter" data-parent="#menuGroup" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseB">
                                                            <span>
                                                                B
                                                            </span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                                        <div aria-controls="collapseJain" aria-expanded="false" class="mu-single-counter" data-parent="#menuGroup" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseC">
                                                            <span>
                                                                C
                                                            </span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                                        <div aria-controls="collapseLunch" aria-expanded="false" class="mu-single-counter" data-parent="#menuGroup" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseD">
                                                            <span>
                                                                D
                                                            </span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                                        <div aria-controls="collapseCocktail" aria-expanded="false" class="mu-single-counter" data-parent="#menuGroup" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseE">
                                                            <span>
                                                                E
                                                            </span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mu-restaurant-menu-content">
                                        <div class="row visible-lg visible-md visible-sm visible-xs collapsable-content">
                                            <div class="container">
                                                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                                    <div class="main-menu-box">
                                                        <hr>
                                                            <div class="collapse" id="collapseA">
                                                                <div class="intro">
                                                                    A
                                                                </div>
                                                                <hr>
                                                                </hr>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div aria-expanded="true" class="collapse" id="collapseB">
                                                                <div class="intro">
                                                                    B
                                                                </div>
                                                                <hr>
                                                                </hr>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div aria-expanded="true" class="collapse" id="collapseC">
                                                                <div class="intro">
                                                                    C
                                                                </div>
                                                                <hr>
                                                                </hr>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div aria-expanded="true" class="collapse" id="collapseD">
                                                                <div class="intro">
                                                                    D
                                                                </div>
                                                                <hr>
                                                                </hr>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div aria-expanded="true" class="collapse" id="collapseE">
                                                                <div class="intro">
                                                                    E
                                                                </div>
                                                                <hr>
                                                                </hr>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </hr>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <hr>
                                            </hr>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
<!-- End Restaurant Menu -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="collapse"]').click(function(event) {
        if ($('.collapse.in').length > 0) {
            $('.collapse.in').collapse('hide')
        }
    });
})
</script>
```

Comment: This seems to work but its not really a smooth transition. When you run your code snippet (it like jumps) rather than changes div's smoothly. Run both snippets (my original and yours) and you might be able to see difference. Any reason why this is? Also the effect has gone where you click on an item list, div appears and if you click back on the same item list it stays open. Is there a way to collapse if it it you click on it again?